# Как сделать полностью прозрачное приложение, но элементы на нем не прозрачные?

Tags: python, ооп, gui, qss, pyqt6

Как сделать полностью прозрачное приложение, но элементы на нем не прозрачные?

```
import QtQuick 6.3
import QtQuick.Window 6.3
import AssistentYuna

Window {
    width: mainScreen.width
    height: mainScreen.height
    opacity: 0.4

    visible: true
    color: "#ffffff"
    maximumHeight: 350
    maximumWidth: 250
    minimumHeight: 350
    minimumWidth: 250
    title: "AssistentYuna"

    Screen01 {
        id: mainScreen
        opacity: 1
        color: "#c2c2c2"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):                       
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName('main_window')
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | 
            Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
        
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        # Важно!: this widget is used as background and rounded corners.
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        # Add user interface to widget
        label = QLabel('Hello, world!')
        label.setObjectName('label')
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            'r', self, clicked=self.close, objectName='closeButton'), 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(label, 2, 0, 5, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(300, 380)        


Stylesheet = """
#Custom_Widget {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 100;
    border: 4px solid #91091E;                   
}
#closeButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    font-family: "Webdings";
    qproperty-text: "r";
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: red;
}
#label {
    color: #91091E;
    font-size: 25pt;
}
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()   # 
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]